# laravel Key does not exist or is not readable in issue

Tags: laravel

I have copy laravel project from one directory to another directory.

But it is not working after copy the project.

Please help me.

Error:

```
[2019-01-30 10:35:14] lumen.ERROR: LogicException: Key path "file:///opt/lampp/htdocs/ghomes/backend/storage/oauth-private.key" does not exist or is not readable in /opt/lampp/htdocs/ghomes/backend/vendor/league/oauth2-server/src/CryptKey.php:45
Stack trace:
```

Comment: try to do : `php artisan key:generate`

Comment: Did you install passport correctly `php artisan passport:install`

Comment: Yes, In a lampp i just copy laravel project, main project is working but copied project is not working.

Comment: Still not getting the solutions, please provide any solutions.

Comment: Hello @Vijay Have you tried my answer? Please discuss my answer then I can try to solve this problem with you

Comment: yes i have tried it.

Comment: @Vijay run this command `php artisan passport:keys`

Comment: @Udhav Sarvaiya: can you please help me to solve my issue.

Comment: yes @Vijay i will try my best, can you please tell me what is your current problem

Comment: I have one project name is project1. Project1 working perfatly, when i copy from Project1 to project2, project2 display token error.

Comment: Is there any step to or key to login my project.

Comment: @Vijay what is full error, please write a full error then i can understand easily

Answer (score -1):

You have not installed the passport correctly. you get this error because *`passport`* is not installed correctly,

Solution is simple Please run this command:

```
php artisan passport:install
```

This command will create the encryption keys needed to generate secure access tokens. In addition, the command will create "personal access" and "password grant" clients which will be used to generate access tokens.

`php artisan passport:keys` This command generates the encryption keys Passport needs in order to generate access token.